# How to restore manually Saved State files of Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, backup, command-line, restore

My MBR crashes quite often. Normally I've multiple terminal windows and usually they're restored after crash.

However from some to time they're not restored, so for that reason I was doing the backup every hour (in cron, not Time Machine) to backup the whole `~/Library/Saved Application State` including `com.apple.Terminal.savedState`.

However when I've replaced back my savedState folder (1. removing the old one, 2. using different type of terminal) and run Terminal - it simply doesn't work as expected (as it seems it doesn't load the state files).

Is there anything that I'm missing? Do I need to do anything extra so Terminal can recognise its state files or simply backing up more folders to keep my window states safe?

The backup folder consist `data.data` (48M), `windows.plist` (empty) and `window_1.data` - `window_56.data` files (total 55M).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `windows.plist` has been corrupted during the backup, as it's empty.

The Terminal restores correctly when doing the following test:

1. Run Terminal.
2. Type anything like: `echo test 1`.
3. Kill the terminal explicitly, e.g.: `killall Terminal`.
4. Run again, it should have the previous message/state.
5. Removing files and restoring from it, it'll have the same state.

The corrupted `.plist` file can be manually rewritten by the following hacky steps:

1. Convert `plist` into its XML representation (Terminal will still recognise it):

   ```
   plutil  -convert xml1 -o windows.plist windows.plist
   ```
2. Edit the file to match its windows id (`NSWindowID`) to the appropriate files. Or create as many new windows manually to have the same files, kill the terminal, replace only the window `.data` files and re-run again.

   However if the data files are not inconsistent with plist file, the Terminal will restore the default session overriding your files.